# set 144hz via xorg.conf

Tags: xorg, monitors

I'm trying to run my monitor, both Asus VG278Q models, under Arch Linux at
144Hz.

Before xrandr is recommended to me, yes, with xrandr I get the monitors to run
at 144Hz.

```bsh
xrandr --output DisplayPort-1 --rate 144 --mode 1920x1080 --primary
xrandr --output DisplayPort-2 --rate 144 --mode 1920x1080
```

But I don't want to use xrandr combined with a shell script in my autostart. I
want to configure X11, that the dpm starts at default the monitors with 144hz.

So I placed my X11 configuration file to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/00-monitors.conf`.

```bsh
Section "Monitor"
  Identifier  "Asus_VG278Q_1"
  VendorName  "Asus"
  ModelName   "VG278Q"
  Modeline    "1920x1080_144.00"  451.72  1920 2080 2296 2672  1080 1081 1084 1174  -HSync +Vsync
  Option      "Primary"   "true"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
  Identifier  "Asus_VG278Q_2"
  VendorName  "Asus"
  ModelName   "VG278Q"
  Modeline    "1920x1080_144.00"  451.72  1920 2080 2296 2672  1080 1081 1084 1174  -HSync +Vsync
  Option      "Primary"   "false"
  Option      "LeftOf"    "Asus_VG278Q_1"
EndSection

Section "Device"
  Identifier  "AMD_RX5700XT"
  Driver      "amdgpu"
  Option      "Asus_VG278Q_1" "DisplayPort-1"
  Option      "Asus_VG278Q_2" "DisplayPort-2"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
  Identifier "AMD_Monitors"
  Device     "AMD_RX5700XT"
  Monitor    "Asus_VG278Q_1"
  Monitor    "Asus_VG278Q_2"
EndSection
```

When I restart the display manager via systemctl (`systemctl restart display-manager.service`), 
I am logged out and must login into a new session about lightdm. But when I use
xrandr to view the used refresh rate I see, that 60Hz is reused.

```bsh
$ xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DisplayPort-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 598mm x 336mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+ 144.00   119.98    99.93    84.90    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DisplayPort-2 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 598mm x 336mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+ 144.00   119.98    99.93    84.90    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
HDMI-A-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Has anyone an idea whats wrong with my x11 configuration?

Volker

Comment: Have a look at `/var/log/Xorg.*.log` to see why X is rejecting the modeline.